# Interpretation of the alpha parameter in the Rational Quadratic Kernel

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

I've been working on Gaussian processes and a problem that keeps bugging me is the alpha parameter on the rational quadratic kernel

[image]

I know that the rational quadratic is an infinite sum of squared exponential and when alpha goes to infinity the Rational Quadratic basically becomes the Squared Exponential kernel.
But how do we interpret the kernel and its behaviour and characteristics if alpha has the specific value of, for example, 0.5 or 1 or 10?